# need guidance on retrieving current price of erc20 tokens for a trading dashboard

Tags: cryptoapi, erc20

I'm in the middle of building a personal trading dashboard and I'm stuck on fetching the current price of any ERC20 token. I've been trying to use the Mobula API, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!